# What's the meaning of "stripped, with debug_info" when I use "file" command for a shared library?

Tags: c++, c, linux, shared-libraries

When I use "file" command on a shared library:

```
file shared_library.so
```

It shows

```
shared_library.so: ELF 32-bit LSB shared object, ARM, EABI5 version 1 (SYSV), dynamically linked, interpreter /system/bin/linker, stripped, with debug_info
```

"*stripped*" means It is stripped. But I don't understand why stripped library still have "*with debug_info*".

Comment: `"stripped"` means the shared object (or any compiled object) has been stripped of its debugging symbols (generally by using `strip -s object`). `strip` removes debugging symbols resulting in a smaller library, faster load times, etc... Generally you think of "Released" code benefiting from being stripped while "Debug" code would not make sense to be stripped. Not everything is always stripped, there are many options, see [strip(1) - Linux manual page](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/strip.1.html)

Comment: Leaving debug symbols in an application or library does not affect memory usage or performance. The linker does not map the symbols into memory. Also see [How does the gcc -g option affect performance?](https://gcc.gnu.org/ml/gcc-help/2005-03/msg00032.html) on the GCC mailing list. I think distro's strip to reduce the on-disk size. Folks who don't care about symbols don't pay the storage costs. Folks who want symbols for debugging can install them.

Answer (score 5):

> But I don't understand why stripped library still have "with debug_info".

This would be the effect of `strip --only-keep-debug file`. From [man strip](https://linux.die.net/man/1/strip):

> --only-keep-debug
>
> Strip a file, removing contents of any sections that would not be stripped by --strip-debug
>   and leaving the debugging sections intact. In ELF files, this preserves all note sections in the output.
>
> ...